# How to reset/restore vscode-pull-request-github extension on my local machine

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not too long ago I found the great VSCode extension [vscode-pull-request-github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github) which I love.

Everything worked just fine for a while until one day I somehow killed the connection to the server, I tried to recover from it without any success.

I reinstalled VScode, wiped the repo and the VS settings, but none of it worked.

I deleted on github the app permission, reinstalled it on another machine (Mac), and everything worked well for a while.

After trying to recover the extension on my main Linux machine, things fail apart again, this time on both machines.

I assume there is something else I need to delete, a public key or something else that allow the connection between my local client and github, but I just do not know what it is and where to find it.

Any cleanup procedure which will allow me to reuse the extension again will be well appreciated.